# How to ask from somebody I can't remember, where did we meet?

Tags: work-environment, politeness, relationships, germany

He is working in the same office building but by a different company.

He welcomed me sometimes already, and it was clear he remembers me from somewhere. Also, I remember his face, however, I can't remember, where did we meet.

I welcomed him back, trying to hide that I don't have any idea, who is he.

The problem is that if he finds that I totally forgot him, it wouldn't make him the best impression. Thus, I would like to avoid it.

However, I am very, very curious, who could he be. I think I should somehow find it out. However, I have no idea, how could I ask it from him, because asking this, I would reveal that I've forgotten him.

P.s. It is Germany.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how you can get away from his suspicion after you ask.

However, people forget. Simply dig a bit about your acquaintance and you can make an educated guess where and when you meet him.

> How long he has been in company B?

Most likely you meet him in the building. Asking this allow you to guesstimate when did that happen. If you met and introduced yourselves casually, how you met is not important and you can just give up and enjoy the friendship.

> Do you both have a common interest?

If yes, try to remember the recent activity and event. You might met him in a conference or gathering.

---

You can then throw a wild statement, hoping he remember the fact better and correct you.

> When I first met you I already know you will be such a good friend.

Followed by

> Isn't that x year ago?
>   Didn't we meet at "insert an event"?

---

**Bonus :** Big chance that they don't remember clearly how you met, too. So just enjoy your friendship.

Even if they do remember, you can shrug it off by complimenting his good memory.

> Really? Wow, you have such a good memory! I think I might have gone old.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like he doesn't remember either.

If he had, he would, like most socially-adept people, have dropped you a clue:  "Ah, I haven't seen you since summer camp in the forest!," or something similar.    So there is no real harm in telling him:  "I remember *you*, but not where we met."  That would not only be friendly, and honest, but would open up your first post-reunion conversation.

Trying to fake your way through a conversation like this can be far more embarrassing (for both parties) than fessing up.

Answer (score 3):

"The problem is that if he finds that I totally forgot him" - that's the thing, you haven't totally forgotten him... you've just forgotten the context around your previous encounter.

This has happened a few times to me because of attending various events and meetups - in fact, one time it led to a moment where I ran into someone I had met previously and we both pointed at each other and simultaneously burst out with "sorry, I don't remember where we met", much to the bemusement of several other people in the room.

As Curt points out, they also seem to be having difficulty in placing you.

Next time I would simply go over and say, "Hi, I know we've met before, but I'm afraid I'm having a bit of trouble remembering when - let me reintroduce myself".